# Zend form element for customized currency

Tags: php, zend-form, currency, zend-form-element

How to extend zend form element to create customized currency field.

For example:

```
$amount = new Example_Form_Element_Currency(1234);
```

The out put should be like this: `$1,234.00`.

I want a custom helper for currency.

Comment: What type of element? Have you tried extending the standard text element? What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking to apply a [filter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.elements.html#zend.form.elements.filters).

I don't think there's a built-in currency filter however it wouldn't be difficult to create one to run the submitted value through [`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) or similar.

```
class My_Filter_Currency implements Zend_Filter_Interface
{
    public function filter($value)
    {
        return '$' . number_format($value, 2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I am working with such a filter too but when returning the values to the controller my function looks dirty. I am looking for a better solution here.

```
                    ->addFilter(
                        'Callback',
                        array( 'callback' => function( $value )
                        {
                            $value = str_replace(',', '.', $value);
                            if( is_numeric($value) ){
                                return number_format( 
                                    doubleval( $value ),
                                    2,
                                    ',',
                                    '.'
                                );
                            }else{
                                return $value;
                            }
                        } )
                    )
```

......

```
public function getAmount()
{
    return doubleval(  str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $this->_value1->getValue() ) ) );
}
```

If you take a look my issues here come with i18n.